# execute some script after compile

Tags: lazarus

i wanna to copy some file after lazarus compiled my project, like Build event in visual studio, I found the similar option in Lazarus:

[image]

but when I press ctrl+f9 to compie, will thrown error:

```
Executing command after missing executable ""
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @KenWhite, is there some similar operation in lazarus?

Comment: @Ken appears to be mistaken here. At least according to the [documentation](http://wiki.freepascal.org/IDE_Window:_Compiler_Options#Execute_after). As I see it the problem is that there is no executable. A bat file is not executable. Prepend your command with `cmd.exe /c` to provide the executable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you are right, i got it

Comment: I think this question is should not be down-vote, it very useful for beginners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read the [documentation](http://wiki.freepascal.org/IDE_Window:_Compiler_Options#Execute_after), you are expected to provide an executable command. A .bat file is not executable which would explain why your command fails.

Prepend your command with `cmd.exe /c` to provide the executable which processes the .bat file.

```
cmd.exe /c "G:\Lazarus project\dll test\copy.bat"
```

Comment: thanks you anwser! but in `C:\>cmd /?` `/C` is means:  Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates. instead of provide a executable file, i am confused now

Comment: `cmd.exe` is an executable file. When you double click on a `.bat` file, it is processed by `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score -1):

change the command to `cmd.exe /c  "G:\Lazarus project\dll test\copy.bat"` will works:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it doesn't explain what is wrong, and why you made this change. I will convert my comment to an answer.